# ASP.NET - LocalReport.Render() - Invalid token for impersonation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, reporting-services

I'm trying to generate a PDF report using local reporting services inside an ASP.NET MVC web application.

Problem is, when the call to the `Render()` method is done inside a separate `Task`, I get an exception:

> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
>   Failed to load expression host assembly.  Details: Invalid token for
>   impersonation - it cannot be duplicated.

If the call to `Render()` is hit by a user request (via controller -> class library) in the same thread, the exception is not thrown.

I'm out of choices at the moment. Things I tried so far:

I've tried wrapping the Task inside a `using` block.

```
// Doesn't work even with (true) or ()
IntPtr currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(false).Token;
Task.Run(() =>
{
    using (WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(currentUser))
    {
        ProcessStart();
    }
});

public static void ProcessStart()
{
    LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();

    ...
    getting data for the report
    ...

    // this statement throws the exception
    byte[] pdfStream = localReport.Render(formatString,
                       deviceInfo,
                       out mimetype,
                       out encoding,
                       out fileNameExtension,
                       out streams,
                       out warnings);

    ...
    saving bytestream to file
    ...
}
```

I checked [THIS POST](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d5845f75-7508-4519-8fb0-4b158c30746d/using-ssrs-local-mode-receive-invalid-token-error-when-trying-to-export-the-report-when-running-in?forum=sqlreportingservices) but I can't see how that could help me since I'm currently just debugging in localhost.

I checked [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501630/rendering-reportviewer-on-another-thread) but it suggests to remove the task and do the reporting in the same thread, which I can't do.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Did you resolve this retaining Task?

Comment: @San Unfortunately I can't remember the exact solution, it's been a while and meanwhile I changed company. If you'd like me to tidy I can delete the question.

Comment: had the same problem just now and figured that inside the `Task` code, the identity is no longer the application pool identity, but `NT-AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`. I will post an answer if I find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my way to the working solution I first started to tinker with the `alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy` configuration flag, which seems to exist to deal with passing impersonation tokens between threads in an ASP.NET request lifecycle, there is some [useful documentation](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/setting-an-aspnet-config-file-per-application-pool) but it was a dead end.

The problem here is the identity, and the fact that `LocalReport.Render` uses sandboxed app domains to compile and execute expressions.

If we could prevent the report engine from creating a sandbox app domain, its code would execute in the same domain and execution context as the calling code, avoiding the additional token propagation that throws the inner exception. Inspecting the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.setbasepermissionsforsandboxappdomain.aspx) for the `LocalReport` class finds us the `ExecuteReportInCurrentAppDomain` method, promising to do just that:

```
public static void ProcessStart()
{
    var localReport = new LocalReport();

    /* ...
     * getting data for the report
     * ... */

    /* prepare to do all rendering in the same appdomain */
    localReport.ExecuteReportInCurrentAppDomain(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Evidence);
    /* now this fails no more */
    byte[] pdfStream = localReport.Render(
        formatString,
        deviceInfo,
        out mimetype,
        out encoding,
        out fileNameExtension,
        out streams,
        out warnings
    );

    /* ...
     * saving bytestream to file 
     * ... */
}
```

I tested it, and it actually works! But there is a downside: The method has been deprecated in .NET 4.0 and higher. It is necessary to add two legacy configuration switches to make it work:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <trust legacyCasModel="true" />
    </system.web>
    <runtime>
         <legacyCasPolicy enabled="true" />    
         <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

If these are not added, calling `ExecuteReportInCurrentAppDomain` throws an exception. I am using this code in production now; I am aware that in future versions of .NET this will likely break - perhaps until then the report engine is improved as well. Adding these legacy CAS support stuff is not recommended of course, it it may have an impact on other parts of your application, for example it will prevent the runtime from using NGEN images from GAC.

To try to plant the request identity on the task context is just as pointless as [setting the `AlwaysFlowImpersonation` flag](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/setting-an-aspnet-config-file-per-application-pool) in the Aspnet.config file.

There are many other problems with this approach overall, for example there is no mechanism in place to prevent the host process to terminate the worker thread and your background task with it.
Several other posts on SO [and elsewhere](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) deal with these additional complications, anyway the most robust solution still is to have a service process running independently from IIS and assigning background tasks to it using a message queue, named pipes or something like that. Starting from .NET framework version 4.5.2, there is the `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` which you could use instead.

As there is so much advice against this, why would we still want to go for it? IMO there is just one very good reason: whenever we want a request to return really fast, and we do not care if the result is discarded. I don't know about OP's user story, but mine permits it: we trigger the request from a SCORM e-learning package on page navigation, and we need to avoid any delay here. if the users navigate away before they consume their asynchronously delivered report, the worker thread can as well terminate the task prematurely.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this! I was so sorry I couldn't remember how I did it and moved off .NET since quite a while. I'm glad a way around has been found. :)